# Insert List Item in an Ordered List using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this type of list item in my ordered list.

```html
<li class="other">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
          <p>Copón</p>
        <p><emoji class="funny"/></p>
        <time>18:08</time>
      </div>
    </li>
```

I want to insert a new list item using javascript. Here is what I am trying to do.

```js
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
 function1();
   }
}
function function1() {
  var str = document.getElementById("query_text").value;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
          return;
  } else {
       var ol = document.getElementById("list_container");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML = '<div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div><div class="msg"><p>Copón</p><p><emoji class="funny"/></p><time>18:08</time></div>';
   ol.appendChild(li);   
   }
  }
```

But the above script is not working.

This is the whole page code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
 function1();
   }
}
function function1() {
  var str = document.getElementById("query_text").value;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
          return;
  } else {
       var ol = document.getElementById("list_container");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML = '<div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div><div class="msg"><p>Copón</p><p><emoji class="funny"/></p><time>18:08</time></div>';
   ol.appendChild(li);   
   }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="menu">
            <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div>
            <div class="name">Alex</div>
            <div class="last">18:09</div>
</div>
    <ol id="list_containe" class="chat">

    <li class="other">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
          <p>Copón</p>
        <p><emoji class="funny"/></p>
        <time>18:08</time>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="self">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HYcn9xO.png" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>Hey there's a new update about this chat UI with more responsive elements! Check it now:</p>
        <p><a href="http://codepen.io/Varo/pen/YPmwpQ" target="parent">Chat UI 2.0</a></p>
        <time>18:09</time>
      </div>
    </li>

    </ol>
    <input class="textarea" id="query_text" type="text" placeholder="Type here!"/><div class="emojis"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Any errors in your console? What would be the expected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

I get

> js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null(…)

That makes sense because `id="list_containe"` is missing the `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected id `list_containe` to `list_container` and clearing input on appending new item

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
 function1();
   }
}
function function1() {
  var str = document.getElementById("query_text").value;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
          return;
  } else {
       var ol = document.getElementById("list_container");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML = '<div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div><div class="msg"><p>Copón</p><p><emoji class="funny"/></p><time>18:08</time></div>';
   ol.appendChild(li);   
          
            document.getElementById("query_text").value = '';
   }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="menu">
            <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div>
            <div class="name">Alex</div>
            <div class="last">18:09</div>
</div>
    <ol id="list_container" class="chat">

    <li class="other">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DY6gND0.png" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
          <p>Copón</p>
        <p><emoji class="funny"/></p>
        <time>18:08</time>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="self">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HYcn9xO.png" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p>Hey there's a new update about this chat UI with more responsive elements! Check it now:</p>
        <p><a href="http://codepen.io/Varo/pen/YPmwpQ" target="parent">Chat UI 2.0</a></p>
        <time>18:09</time>
      </div>
    </li>

    </ol>
    <input class="textarea" id="query_text" type="text" placeholder="Type here!"/><div class="emojis"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain what this is/means?